# Display the index of the selected item in a custom DetailsList onRenderCheckbox

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I'm using ui-fabric and have a DetailsList with multi-select enabled. I want to be able to render the position of the selected item inside the checkbox, instead of the checkmark.

I defined a custom `onRenderCheckbox` function that I'm passing the DetailsList. I also have a sample of the code in a Codepen: https://codepen.io/isabelacmor/pen/gOONYaq?editors=0010

```
renderOrderedCheckbox = (props?: IDetailsListCheckboxProps): JSX.Element => {
      return (
        // Checkbox handles the click through its props, so don't allow outside changes
        <div style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
          <Checkbox
            checked={props!.checked}
            styles={{
              label: {
                selectors: {
                   // I want the content to render the index of that item in the selection array
                  '& > div > i::before': { content: `"${'test'}"` },
                },
              },
            }}
            checkmarkIconProps={{
              iconName: '',
              styles: {
                root: {
                  display: 'flex',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                },
              },
            }}
          />
        </div>
      );
    };
```

I need to replace the "test" string I'm setting `content` to with the index of that item in my selection array (`this._selection`). But it doesn't seem that `onRenderCheckbox` has any context into which item it's rendering the `Checkbox` for.

**Is there a way to give `onRenderCheckbox` this context?** If I know what item the current `Checkbox` is referring to, I can easily look up the item in `this._selection` to populate the `content` CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> But it doesn't seem that onRenderCheckbox has any context into which
>   item it's rendering the Checkbox for

that's right, `row` props are not getting passed down into `Checkbox` component.

> Is there a way to give `onRenderCheckbox` this context?

One option to consider would be to share row properties between `DetailsRow` and `CheckBox` components, [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) comes to the rescue here, here is a list of changes:

a) [create a Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) object to keep `details row` props:

```
const DetailsRowContext = React.createContext({} as IDetailsRowProps);
```

b) override `onRenderRow` event handler in order to pass *row properties* via Provider React component:

```
 <DetailsList
      onRenderRow={this.renderRow}
      ...
    />
```

where

```
private renderRow(
    rowProps: IDetailsRowProps,
    defaultRender: IRenderFunction<IDetailsRowProps>
  ): JSX.Element {
    return <DetailsRowContext.Provider value={{...rowProps}}> {defaultRender({ ...rowProps })}</DetailsRowContext.Provider>;
  }
```

c)and finally update `renderOrderedCheckbox` event handler to consume *row properties*:

```
const details = React.useContext(DetailsRowContext);
```

[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/oNgNeWr?editors=0011)

**Option 2**

Instead of customizing checkbox (`onRenderCheckbox` event) per `DetailsList`, checkbox could be customized per row via `IDetailsRowBaseProps.onRenderDetailsCheckbox`, this way additional properties  could be passed per row, for example:

```
private renderRow(
    rowProps: IDetailsRowProps,
    defaultRender: IRenderFunction<IDetailsRowProps>
  ): JSX.Element {
    let label = "";
    if ("itemIndex" in rowProps) {
      label = this.state.items[rowProps.itemIndex].checkboxLabel;
    }

    rowProps.onRenderDetailsCheckbox = (props: IDetailsCheckboxProps) => {
      return this.renderDetailsCheckbox(props!.checked, label);
    };

    return <div>{defaultRender({ ...rowProps })}</div>;
}
```

[Updated Codepen 2](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/OJPVWBd?editors=0010)

Comment: Thanks Vadim for the examples. I see in the updated CodePen that the item’s index is shown in the Checkbox, but what I’m actually looking to do is show the index of that item in my selection. For example, if I check the first three items, the Checkboxes should show “0,1,2”. Then if I uncheck the first time and check the fourth, the Checkboxes should show “unchecked, 0,1,2”. Maybe I can rework your example with Context to achieve this.

Comment: @isabelacmor, given the previous comment, the answer has been updated with another approach (option 2), it appears this is what you are looking for..